# Aptitude - disable saving selections

Tags: aptitude

If I mark packages to install in aptitude but I exits from aptitude without installing this packages aptitude remember this selections. How to prevent aptitude to remember this selections? I want to run aptitude with cleared selections, like in Synaptic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no parameter to clear the selection and no settings in the <kbd>Options</kbd>-menu.

You have to use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to activate the menu
- <kbd>E</kbd>, the little `e` in `Cancel pending actions`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nothing happens because there is no action for key E.

Comment: Sure; answer updated.

Comment: I have different language version of aptitude and keyboard shortcut is ctrl+t-p.